Making a checkbox value unique in a reusable component. React Native
EDITED - I re-architected the flow to make it less verbose. Hopefully this is more digestable
I have a set of screens (Yellow, Orange, Green, etc) and each have 5 cards that will display and array of video thumbnails, title etc. Each card can hold any number of thumbnails. The way that the user adds videos/thumbnails to these cards (collections) is by way of a modal that contains the data and each item has a checkbox. After selecting the checkboxes and closing the modal they get added to the card.
This works. Except, when I open the modal from another card, the checkboxes from the previous selection are already selected. I need every modal to open with the checkboxes selected from the card that opened it
NOTE: The checkbox component is from React Native Paper - see it here. It doesn't have a value property. It uses a status which I am already implementing.
Also, each card is in separate files to maintain a separation of concerns and not mixing prop values by accident. Yet, the checkbox insist on remembering the last selection.
Here is the logic code for the yellow screen
// This function gets triggered by the checkbox selection and 
// populates the state `selectedwaza` 
// it also handles the checked and unchecked status
const selectItem = (item, index) => {
  const newData = [...dropdowndata];
  const newItem = newData[index];

  newItem.checked = !item.checked;
  setChecked(!checked)
  setDropdownData(newData);    

  if (newItem.checked) {
    if (!selectedwaza.includes(newItem)) {
      setSelectedWaza(prev => [...prev, newItem]); 
    }
  } else {
    setSelectedWaza(prev => prev.filter(i => i.title !== newItem.title));
  }
}

And below in my view:
// I mad the items to pick from and assign a checkbox to each item
{dropdown_collection.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text style={{color: activeColors.textcolor}} >
            {item.title}
        </Text> 
        <Checkbox.Item
            mode='android'
            color={activeColors.primary}
            status={item.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
            onPress={() => selectItem(item, index)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
})}


EDIT 2 I can see that although the checkboxes stay checked, their value isnt carrying over. I can still open the next set of cards and select what I want and it will only add those newly selected and ignore what is already remembered from the previous use. However that is impractical because if I want to add one that is already shown selected, I have to de-select it first and select it once again. I figure a simple "clear the checkboxes when closing the modal" approach will be a good hack. But that's not working either. I'm posting the functions in question in case someone else is looking at this and wants to help me out
const selectItem = (item, index) => {

  const newData = [...dropdownCollection];
  const newItem = newData[index];

  newItem.checked = !item.checked;
  setChecked(!checked)  

  if (newItem.checked) {
    if (!selectedwaza.includes(newItem)) {
      setSelectedWaza(prev => [...prev, newItem]); 
    }
  } else {
    setSelectedWaza(prev => prev.filter(i => i.title !== newItem.title));
  }
}

// Function to clear all checkboxes
const handleCloseModal = () => {
  setModalVisible(false);
  const clearedData = dropdown_collection.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    checked: false
  }));
  // Update your state with the cleared data
  setDropdownCollection(clearedData);
};

For those of you who need more code to see, see the whole page below. Others who need just the relevant code ignore below
import React, {useContext, useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, Animated, Pressable, Modal, ActivityIndicator  } from 'react-native'
import { colors } from '../../../../assets/theme/config';
import { ThemeContext } from '../../../../context/ThemeContext';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-native-paper';
import SearchField from '../../../../components/SearchField';
import ashiwaza from '../../../../assets/data/nagewaza/ashiwaza';
import koshiwaza from '../../../../assets/data/nagewaza/koshiwaza';
import masutemiwaza from '../../../../assets/data/nagewaza/masutemiwaza';
import yokosutemiwaza from '../../../../assets/data/nagewaza/yokosutemiwaza';
import tewaza from '../../../../assets/data/nagewaza/tewaza';

const dropdown_collection = [...tewaza, ...ashiwaza, ...koshiwaza, ...masutemiwaza, ...yokosutemiwaza]

import {db, auth} from '../../../../firebase';
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import { doc, getDoc, updateDoc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const ITEM_SIZE = 180;
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 145;
const QTY = 8

const GokyoNowaza = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [waza, setWaza] = useState([])
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  const [selectedwaza, setSelectedWaza] = useState([])
  const [dropdownCollection, setDropdownCollection] = useState(dropdown_collection);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const isLoading = false
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // build the collection from selecting the checkboxes
  const selectItem = (item, index) => {

    const newData = [...dropdownCollection];
    const newItem = newData[index];

    newItem.checked = !item.checked;
    setChecked(!checked)  

    if (newItem.checked) {
      if (!selectedwaza.includes(newItem)) {
        setSelectedWaza(prev => [...prev, newItem]); 
      }
    } else {
      setSelectedWaza(prev => prev.filter(i => i.title !== newItem.title));
    }
  }

  // Function to clear all checkboxes
  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    const clearedData = dropdown_collection.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      checked: false
    }));
    // Update your state with the cleared data
    setDropdownCollection(clearedData);
  };

  //set collection to data
  const handleTestCollection = async () => {
    const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);
  
    try {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  
      // Prepare the data to be set or updated
      const gokyuData = docSnap.exists() && docSnap.data().gokyu 
        ? docSnap.data().gokyu 
        : {};

      gokyuData.gokyoNoWaza = Array.isArray(selectedwaza) 
        ? [...selectedwaza] 
        : gokyuData.gokyoNoWaza || [];

      // Set or update the document
      await setDoc(docRef, { gokyu: gokyuData }, { merge: true });
      console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    }
  }

  
  //display the colleciton on load
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {        
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if(user) {      
          const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
          user !== null || user !== undefined
          const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);        

          getDoc(docRef).then((docSnap) => {
            const data = docSnap.data().gokyu?.gokyoNoWaza || [];
            if (docSnap.exists()){
              setSelectedWaza(data);        
            } else {
              console.log("nothing here"); 
            }      
          });
        } 
      }); 
    }

    getUser();
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={[{backgroundColor: activeColors.bgalt}, styles.card]}>
      <View style={styles.sectionLabelAndButton}>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor, fontSize:18, fontWeight:'bold'}]}>
              Gokyo No Waza  
            </Text>
          </View>
            
          <View>
            <Text style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor, fontSize:18, fontWeight:'normal'}]}>
              Select {QTY} throws 
            </Text>            
          </View> 
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttons} >
          <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => handleTestCollection()}  
            style={[{backgroundColor:activeColors.primary}, styles.addiconbutton]}>
            <Icon name="content-save" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}  
            style={[{backgroundColor:activeColors.primary}, styles.addiconbutton]}>
            <Icon name="plus" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>        
      </View>  

      <Animated.FlatList
        ref={ref}
        data={selectedwaza}
        horizontal
        initialNumToRender={10}
        initialScrollIndex={index}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
        snapToOffsets={[...Array(waza.length).keys()].map(i => i * ITEM_SIZE)}
        decelerationRate={0}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        onEndReached={() => {
          setWaza([...waza]);
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignItems: 'flex-start',
        }}
        renderItem={
          ({item, index: fIndex}) => {
            return (
              <View key={fIndex} style={{width:ITEM_SIZE * .6, marginVertical:20, marginRight: 20}}> 
                <View style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor, backgroundColor: activeColors.bgalt,}, styles.counter]}>
                  <Text style={{color: activeColors.textcolor}}>{fIndex + 1}</Text> 
                </View>    
                <View style={[styles.overlay]}>
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TechniqueDetails', {data: item})}  
                    style={[{backgroundColor:activeColors.primary}, styles.playbutton]}>
                    <Icon name="play" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>                  
                </View>
                <Animated.View>         
                  <Image source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/images/${item.thumbnail}` }} 
                  style={styles.thumbnail}/>
                  <Text 
                    numberOfLines={2}
                    style={{
                      width: ITEM_SIZE * .6,
                      color:activeColors.textcolor, 
                      fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }}>  
                    {item.title} 
                  </Text>   
                </Animated.View>   
              </View>   
            )
          }
        }
      />
      <Modal animationType="slide" visible={modalVisible} transparent={true}>
        <View 
          style={[{backgroundColor: activeColors.overlay}, styles.container]}>
          {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator size={70} color={colors.tertiary} />}

          {!isLoading && (
            <View style={[styles.modalView, { backgroundColor: activeColors.bgalt }]}>
              <View style={{width: "100%", alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"space-between", flexDirection:"row"}}>
                <Text style={[{color:activeColors.primary }, styles.modalheading]}>
                  Techniques
                </Text>
                <Pressable onPress={handleCloseModal}>
                  <Icon name="close" size={24} color={activeColors.textcolor} />
                </Pressable>
              </View>
              
              <View style={styles.decisionRow}>
                <SearchField value={value} onChangeText={setValue} style={{backgroundColor: activeColors.bg}} />
                <View style={[{backgroundColor: activeColors.bgalt}, styles.searchcontainer]}>
                  {dropdown_collection.map((item, index) => {
                    if(value === "" ) {
                      return null
                    } else if(
                        item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) || item.english.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                      ) 
                    {
                      return (
                        <View key={index} style={styles.searchitems}>
                          <View style={styles.metadata}>
                            <Image source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/images/${item.thumbnail}` }} style={styles.searchresultsthumbnail}/>
                            <View>
                              <Text style={{color: activeColors.textcolor}} >{item.title}</Text>
                              <Text style={{color: activeColors.textcolor, fontSize:12}} >{item.english}</Text>
                            </View>  
                          </View>
                          <View style={styles.buttongroup}>
                            <Checkbox.Item
                              mode='android'
                              color={activeColors.primary}
                              status={item.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                              onPress={() => selectItem(item, index)}
                            />
                          </View>   
                        </View>
                      )
                    }
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
}

export default GokyoNowaza


There's a lot of code included in your sample that doesn't relate to the described issue. Can you edit it to become a [mre] with only the absolutely necessary code to reproduce the issue?

@jsejcksn reproducible? Not unless you have expo running in an emulator and all the dependencies necessary. I decided a different route that is not reusable but it's less verbose. I'll update

@jsejcksn I think it's much cleaner now if you want to take a look. Let me know if you need me to add anything to it.

Also spreading creates a shallow copy so are the items in the array objects? Are you looping over the updated list or the static one created outside of the modal component?

@morganney I had the entire screen code there before minus trivial stuff like other functionalities and styles and there were complaints that it was too much code. I'll update the "entire" file code below it as an extra reference

I updated with the whole thing. But you may be right SetDropdownData creates a collection from the group of checkboxes collected. That may very well be part of the problem

I wouldn't be against giving you temp access to the github as a collab. But that's up to you

The crux of your issue appears to be: const foo = { name: 'foo' }; const bar = { name: 'bar' }; const a = [foo, bar]; const b = [...a]; b[0].checked = true; Now if you do a[0].checked it will also be true.

You can try refactoring your code, or maybe replace the spreads with structuredClone. I would suggest the former.

I don’t want to impose. I understand. Your explanation makes as to why they’re both true. Do you have an answer or is the code shown not enough to conjure up a solution?

In selectItem create a deep clone of dropdown data and then loop over that list instead of the static one created outside of the component.

If your list is large consider a simpler/flat data structure that only references unique identifiers for your dropdown items.

Maybe I'm not grasping the methodology or how to do it correctly, but that didn't work. Btw, I had to use lodash instead since structuredClone is for Web implementation. This is native code

In the code you provided, in this exact part:
dropdown_collection.map((item, index) => {
  if (value === '') {
    return null;
  } else if (
    item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
    item.english.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
  ) {
    return (
      <View key={index} style={styles.searchitems}>
        <View style={styles.metadata}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/images/${item.thumbnail}` }}
            style={styles.searchresultsthumbnail}
          />
          <View>
            <Text style={{ color: activeColors.textcolor }}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: activeColors.textcolor, fontSize: 12 }}>{item.english}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttongroup}>
          <Checkbox.Item
            mode='android'
            color={activeColors.primary}
            status={item.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
            onPress={() => selectItem(item, index)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

You should map the state, not dropdown_collection. The handleCloseModal function clears the data of the state dropdownCollection, but you're returning dropdown_collection.

Thank you. I wish it kept the ones that are selected According to each card I click on rather than a blank slate, but this works better than not working at all. Thanks

@LOTUSMS Then you need another approach. You need to handle the state outside of the component and pass it to it. So, you basically want to keep the state of all cards. I think it's a lot easier that way. I think the best practice will be just to create a context that manages the states of these cards.
